# How to include first assigned category in the post URL?

Tags: categories, permalinks

What are the options for creating URLs like:

*site.com/category-name/post-name*

Where, "category-name" is the first category that the post was assigned to (in the event that the post is assigned to multiple categories)

Note: if the post is assigned to "uncategorized", I don't want to display the category name in the URL, so in that case, I just want

*site.com/post-name*

PS: it will also require the removal of the word "category" from the URL. I was able to get that done with the plugin "no category base", however, it does not include the parent category name in the URL to a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the category with lowest ID is used.

If you want control over what the category is, you can try the Hikari Category Permalink plugin, which allows you to choose which post category is used for the permalink.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hikari-category-permalink/